# Force LaTeX to use binary operation spacing to the right of a + sign only

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I want to typeset '+1', as we would write here on TeX-LaTeX Stack Exchange.

Now, as I see it, the '+' is a binary operator here. I am actually adding 1 to something. I'm not using it to denote the positivity of 1, I'm using it to denote the operation of addition. However, what I'm adding 1 to isn't stated. (It is an upvote on the post, but we do not write 'post + 1', we just write '+1').

If I, then, type `+1` I get

[image]

Which is the unary operation spacing. I tried `$\mathbin{+} 1$`, but that didn't do anything:

[image]

Next I tried `{} + 1` which did use the correct binary operation spacing, but added the spacing before the '+' sign, giving me a small leading space. I don't actually really want this, since I'm not stating what I'm adding 1 to. I want the space after the '+' sign, but not before, which I think is correct. I could add manual, visual correction, but I'm not sure what values to use and would *prefer* a less quick and dirty solution if one exists.

[image]

Code for above image:

```
${} +1$ \\
$+1$
```

Comment: Personally, I think the `$+1$` is just fine, but what about `$+\,1$` or `$+\;1$`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
${} +1$

${}\mkern-\medmuskip+1$

$+\:1$

$+1$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good answer +1 :P Is there any reason why you kern away `\medmuskip` in option 2 but add `\:` in option 3?

Comment: @Au101: You can either consider the `+` as a binary operator and *remove* the one side's spacing (option 2) or consider it an ordinal symbol and *add* the appropriate spacing (option 3).

Comment: Indeed yes :) I was wondering why you had used two different spacing commands, though, for what I assume (?) is the same amount of space. Are they equivalent here (or, indeed, always)?

Comment: @Au101: They are here, since you've only used a unary `+`. Other places you may have to force a unary plus to get the appropriate spacing `{+}\:` (option 3).

Comment: I see, thanks very much :) I'll accept in the morning if nobody's added anything else

Comment: `$\mkern-\medmuskip{}+1$`, "anticipating" the leading space, would also work.

Answer (score 3):

Here's it, implemented in plain TeX (just use `\newcommand` instead of `\def` for LaTeX and `\mspace{-\medmuskip}` instead of `\mskip-\medmuskip` if you also load `amsmath`).

```
\overfullrule=0pt % don't print the overfull rule

\def\addone{\mathord{}\mskip-\medmuskip+1}

%%% LaTeX+amsmath version
%%\newcommand{\addone}{\mathord{}\mspace{-\medmuskip}+1}

``$\addone$''

X\hbox to 0pt{$\addone$}\qquad X\hbox to 50pt{$\addone$}

\def\badaddone{{}\mkern-\medmuskip+1}

``$\badaddone$''

X\hbox to 0pt{$\badaddone$}\qquad X\hbox to 50pt{$\badaddone$}

\bye
```

In the first part I define the command: it inserts an ordinary symbol, then a math skip that counteracts the one automatically inserted by a binary atom, then `+` and finally `1`. The three examples show the behavior at natural size, maximum shrink and exaggerated stretch.

The second part deals with the difference between `\mskip` and `\mkern`. Since `\medmuskip` usually holds a stretchable and shrinkable glue, it's important to distinguish between the two and the examples show why. With `\mkern-\medmuskip` the stretch and shrink components do not cancel and so they can act: and they do.

[image]