# Bespoke environment for systems of linear equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, arrays

### My problem

I often write systems of linear equations, with the following alignment requirements :

- all multiple of the unknowns should be right-aligned
- all `+`, `-` and `=` operation signs should be centered, with proper left/right spacing for those "fully-featured" equations

[image]

### My original MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
My matrix is :
$M =
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  -1 & 2 & -3 \\
   4 & 0 & -1 \\
   7 & 8 &  9 \\
\end{bmatrix*}
$
thus the equation $M X = X$
reads :
$
\def\arraycolsep{0pt}
\left \{
\begin{array}{*3{rc}r}
  - x & {}+{} & 2 y & {}-{} & 3 z & {}={} & x \\
  4 x &       &     & {}-{} &   z & {}={} & y \\
  7 x & {}+{} & 8 y & {}+{} & 9 z & {}={} & z \\
\end{array}
\right.
$
\end{document}
```

### My wish

I do not see how to do that using the environments defined in the `amsmath` or `mathtools` package

What I would like is to have a `linearEquations` environment enabling me to simply write :

```
\begin{linearEquations}{3}
  - x & + & 2 y & - & 3 z & = & x \\
  4 x &   &     & - &   z & = & y \\
  7 x & + & 8 y & + & 9 z & = & z \\
\end{linearEquations}
```

to produce the same result.

### My attempt

What I have tried so far is something like :

```
\newenvironment{linearEquations}[1]
{
  %before
  \def\arraycolsep{0pt}
  \left \{
  \begin{array}{*#1{r@{{}}c@{{}}}r}
}
{
  %after
  \end{array}
  \right.
}
```

but it does not yield the proper `{}` spacing before/after the operation signs

Can you help ?  Cheers,

### A possible solution

As per [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274804/116936), the line `\begin{array}{*#1{r@{\:}c@{\:}}r}` seems to work in this case, but maybe only does so in certain cases ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest making two changes to the setup of the `linearEquations` environment:

- use `\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}`, not `\def\arraycolsep{0pt}`; and
- define a new column type called, say, `C` for the columns of binary and relational operators:

  ```
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
  ```

With these modifications, you custom environment should be fine:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
\newenvironment{linearEquations}[1]{%
  %before
  \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
  \left\{\,
  \begin{array}{*{#1}{rC}r}}{%
  %after
  \end{array}
  \right.
}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{linearEquations}{3}
  - x & + & 2 y & - & 3 z & = & x \\
  4 x &   &     & - &   z & = & y \\
  7 x & + & 8 y & + & 9 z & = & z \\ 
\end{linearEquations}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}
My matrix is:
$M =
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  -1 & 2 & -3 \\
   4 & 0 & -1 \\
   7 & 8 &  9 \\
\end{bmatrix*}
$
thus the equation $M X = X$
reads:
\systeme{
 -x+2y-3z=x,
 4x-z=y,
 7x+8y+9z=z
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow ! I did not expect this ! How does one find all these amazing packages on CTAN ?

Comment: @marsupilam http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=linear+system

Comment: See the question and its answers : [Alignment of multiple variables in a linear system](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144610/alignment-of-multiple-variables-in-a-linear-system)